# What scores do I assign to concentrations in Deadlands Classic?

Tags: character-creation, deadlands-classic

The Deadlands Classic rulebook says that if an aptitude lists concentrations then you must choose one, and that for 3 points you can choose an additional concentration.

The sample character given makes it clear that *Shootin'* concentrations all end up with the same score as the base aptitude.

But then a complication arises: *Professional* concentrations are all treated like distinct aptitudes and have their own score. It would be simple enough to assume that the usual concentration rules apply to most aptitudes, but *Professional* concentrations have a different system.

But then *Languages* are **implied** to work as distinct aptitudes too, but the rulebook doesn't explicitly say this.

And what about *Academia*? Should each concentration be a unique aptitude like *Professional*, or should it be like *Shootin'*?

And what about *Fightin'*? I assumed it should be like *Shootin'*, but then the official character sheet gives space to put scores next to each concentration, much like it does for *Professional*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Concentrations are Related unless noted otherwise.

*Academia* ends with:

> *Academia* concentrations are rarely related.

informing the reader that, unless the Marshal judges otherwise, *academia* concentrations are separate aptitudes. The aptitudes with similar notes are *academia*, *professional*, *science*, and *trade*. All other aptitudes have "related" Concentrations unless the Marshal says otherwise.

So, new related concentrations are always at the same level as the rest of the aptitude. 
 New unrelated concentrations are bought as entirely new aptitudes. 
 If it's not one of the four listed aptitudes then the various concentrations are probably related (unless the Marshal says otherwise).